# How to add a border to a layout or image?

Tags: ios, delphi, border, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

How can I add a shadowed background to a TLayout or image, or any control for that matter ? What is the best way to do this, without having to stack images? I've found that a TPanel should have a border property but I am not finding that property. ? Am I missing something ? Or is there a different technique I should be using ?

I am working with Delphi Xe5 building an iOS application.

Answer (score 4):

See a summary of effects in FireMonkey, [`FireMonkey Image Effects`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/FireMonkey_Image_Effects).

Quote:

> `"These effects are not limited to bitmap image data; effects can be applied to the pixels of any 2D control in the user interface."`

In your case, the [`FMX.Effects.TShadowEffect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Effects.TShadowEffect) is what you are looking for.

> "Beside the properties provided by [TEffect](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Effects.TEffect), **TShadowEffect** provides five specific properties: [Direction](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Effects.TShadowEffect.Direction), [Distance](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Effects.TShadowEffect.Distance), [Opacity](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Effects.TShadowEffect.Opacity), [ShadowColor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Effects.TShadowEffect.ShadowColor), and [Softness](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Effects.TShadowEffect.Softness)."

To learn how to apply an effect to your control, see [`Applying_FireMonkey_Image_Effects`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Applying_FireMonkey_Image_Effects).